# Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I want to count  total number of the natural solutions (different from 0) of the equation  $2x + 3y + z = 100$, but don't know how. How can I calculate it using *Mathematica*? I tried:

```
Solve[{2*x + 3*y + z == 100, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

Comment: use `Length[]` on the result ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
sols = Solve[{2*x + 3*y + z == 100, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, 
        {x, y, z}, Integers];
Length@sols
```

Answer (score 30):

There is an especially useful function for this kind of task: `FrobeniusSolve[{a, b, c}, d]` for finding the list of all solutions to the equation `a x + b y + c z == d`, where `a`,`b`,`c` are given positive integers and `d` is an integer, while `x`,`y`,`z` are non-negative integers to be found. There are many solutions (`884` of them):

```
FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 1}, 100] // Short
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 100}, {0, 1, 97}, {0, 2, 94}, {0, 3, 91}, <<876>>, {48, 0, 4},
>  {48, 1, 1},  {49, 0, 2}, {50, 0, 0}}
> ```

Note that I used `Short` which omitted `876` solutions. 
If you need only positive solutions you can use e.g. `DeleteCases` to get lists free of `0`:

```
DeleteCases[ FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 1}, 100], {___, 0, ___}] // Length
```

> ```
>  784
> ```

**Edit**

`FrobeniusSolve` is not a superfluous function since it is much more efficient than an adequate use of `Solve`. Consider e.g. the analogous equation `2 x + 3 y + z == 1000`. We compare the timings of solving the same equation:

```
Solve[{2*x + 3*y + z == 1000, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}, Integers] //
Length // AbsoluteTiming
FrobeniusSolve[ {2, 3, 1}, 1000] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {76.9510000, 83834}
>   {0.1900000, 83834}
> ```

This huge efficiency difference doesn't really change if we are to find positive solutions:

```
Solve[{2*x + 3*y + z == 1000, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, Integers] //
Length // AbsoluteTiming
DeleteCases[ FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 1}, 1000], {___, 0, ___}] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {77.9720000, 82834}
>   {0.2420000, 82834}
> ```

Moreover, the lists of solutions have the same orderings; e.g.:

```
DeleteCases[ FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 1}, 200], {___, 0, ___}] === 
Solve[{2*x + 3*y + z == 200, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}, Integers][[All, All, 2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: +1 for my favorite `Frobenius*` functions!

Comment: @Silvia Thanks ! Functions like `FrobeniusSolve` are indeed really useful. I think its documentation might be a bit more comprehensive.

Answer (score 7):

There are also power series methods for counting these.

```
SeriesCoefficient[
 x^(1 + 2 + 3)/(1 - x^1)*1/(1 - x^2)*1/(1 - x^3), {x, 0, 100}]

(* Out[118]= 784 *)
```

See also ["Supplement to 'Perplexities Related to Fourier's 17 Line Problem'."](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mm_supplements/index.html)

Comment: Generating functions can be nice sometimes...