# Is there a way to use functions like Prime[n] within Solve[]?

Tags: equation-solving, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to see if a number can be written as the sum of two prime numbers. Ideally, I would like to use

```
Solve[ Prime[n] + Prime[m] == 100, {n, m}]
```

But that simply doesn't work in *Mathematica*.

So is there another way to implement this?

Comment: I also realize that this probably isn't an efficient way of doing this, but it minimizes programmer effort :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If not assumed otherwise `m` and `n` can be whatever, so you can  do e.g. this :

```
Solve[ Prime[n] + Prime[m] == 100, {n, m}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{n -> 2, m -> 25}, {n -> 5, m -> 24}, {n -> 7, m -> 23}, {n -> 10, m -> 20}, 
>  {n -> 13, m -> 17}, {n -> 15, m -> 16}, {n -> 16, m -> 15}, {n -> 17, m -> 13}, 
>  {n -> 20, m -> 10}, {n -> 23, m -> 7}, {n -> 24, m -> 5}, {n -> 25, m -> 2}}
> ```

or in a different (and much better) way :

```
PrimePi @ {n, m} /. Solve[n + m == 100, {n, m}, Primes]
```

`PrimePi` and `Prime` are `Listable`.

### Edit

Since there are many ways in `Mathematica` to solve problems I add another one :

```
PrimePi @ Select[ FrobeniusSolve[ {1, 1}, 100], And @@ PrimeQ @ # &]
```

> ```
> {{ 2, 25}, { 5, 24}, { 7, 23}, {10, 20}, {13, 17}, {15, 16},
>  {16, 15}, {17, 13}, {20, 10}, {23, 7 }, {24, 5 }, {25, 2 }}
> ```

This way is competitive because `FrobeniusSolve` is much faster than `Solve` or `Reduce`, I recommend to take a look at this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation/10569#10569) for an interesting comparison.

### Edit 2

To compare efficency of two `Solve` approches, let's evaluate :

```
sp = Table[{k, PrimePi @ {n, m} /. Solve[n + m == 100 k, {n, m}, Primes]; // AbsoluteTiming
            // First}, {k, 20}];
si = Table[{k, Solve[ Prime[n] + Prime[m] == 100 k, {n, m}, Integers]; // AbsoluteTiming 
           // First}, {k, 20}];
```

using a new (in `Mathematica 9`) option `PlotLegends` :

```
ListPlot[ Tooltip @ {sp, si}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, AspectRatio -> 1/2,
          AxesLabel -> {k, "timings"}, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> 
          Placed[{ Style["Solve over the Primes", Large], 
                   Style["Solve over the Integers", Large]}, {Right, Center}],
          ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Timings are roughly `20` times better for solving over the primes :

```
si[[18 ;;]]
sp[[18 ;;]]
```

> ```
> {{18, 2.582000}, {19, 2.571000}, {20, 2.707000}}
>  {18, 0.207000}, {19, 0.127000}, {20, 0.142000}}
> ```

Now, let's compare `Solve` over the primes and `FrobeniusSolve` approach. Instead of `Select[...]` we take `Cases[...]` (suggested by Rojo in the comments) since the latter appears to be slightly faster.

```
spp = Table[{k, PrimePi @ {n, m} /. Solve[n + m == 500 k, {n, m}, Primes];
             // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {k, 20}];
cfs = Table[{k, PrimePi @ Cases[ FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, 500 k], {_?PrimeQ ..}]; 
            // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {k, 20}];

ListPlot[ Tooltip @ {cfs, spp}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
          PlotLegends -> Placed[{ Style["Cases and FrobeniusSolve", 30], 
                                  Style["Solve over the Primes", 30]}, Right], 
          Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {k, "timings"}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

We can see that timings for `FrobeniousSolve`  are roughly `20-40 %` better than for the `Solve` over `Primes` approach :

```
cfs[[18 ;;, 2]]
spp[[18 ;;, 2]]
```

> ```
> {0.702000, 0.412000, 0.412000}
> {0.866000, 0.576000, 0.591000}
> ```

The larger numbers we deal with the better  is the `FroneniousSolve` approach. This issue is even clearer if we have more variables.
The oscillating pattern of the above plots of timings is coupled to the number of prime solutions $(m, n)$ to this equation $m + n = k\;$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: `Solve[ k + 2*m^2 == 100 && k \[Element] Primes, {n, m}, Integers]`

Comment: `Cases[100~IntegerPartitions~{2}, {_?PrimeQ ..}]`, (almost) equivalent to your last optoin

Comment: @Rojo Good point, however I prefer `FrobeniusSolve` rather than `IntegerPartitions` since the latter yields solutions without ordering, i.e. there are only `{a,b}` pairs unlike in the former `{a,b}` and `{b,a}`.

Answer (score 9):

You can do :

```
Reduce[Prime[n] + Prime[m] == 100, {n, m}, Integers]
```