# How to define a list that contains all primes less than x?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

how can I define my own list in which I have all primes less than x?

Comment: `Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ x`. See e.g. this question [What is so special about Prime?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) to get an idea about possible limitations of this approach.

Comment: Or `Cases[Range@x, _?PrimeQ]` But Artes version is much faster :)

Comment: @Öskå  A possible alternative would be the `NextPrime` function see e.g. [Why does iterating Prime in reverse order require much more time?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/why-does-iterating-prime-in-reverse-order-require-much-more-time/15862#15862) for completing the method above.

Comment: I would recommend also a closer look at this question [Is there a way to use functions like Prime within Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/is-there-a-way-to-use-functions-like-primen-within-solve)

Comment: @Artes reply the question?

Comment: @Öskå I suggest you can do it. I have seen recently such a question but haven't found it yet.

Comment: I will CW it tomorrow if you haven't found it :)

Answer (score 4):

As [Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes) said in his [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47436/how-to-define-a-list-that-contains-all-primes-less-than-x#comment140730_47436):

> `Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ x`. See e.g. this question [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) to get an idea about possible limitations of this approach.

Application of what is being said:

```
primeInf[x_] := Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ x
primeInf@20
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
> ```