# Output of a Print in a list

Tags: printing

I'just starting with Mathematica and therefore I was having a small question.

It must be somewhere on Internet but I can't find it.

My question is the following.

I would like to get my values after having computed a `Print[...]` in a list.

I wanted to print the prime numbers <5

```
For[i=1,i<5,i++,
Print[Prime[i]];
]
```

> ```
> Out:
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 7
> ```

But I would like to get these 4 values such as: `{2,3,5,7}`
How do I compute that?
I already tried `Print[List[Prime[i]]` but that gave me `{2} {3} {5} {7}`.
Thank you!

And if I want to Print the prime values below a certain upperbound, let's say 10.

```
For[i=1,Prime[i]<10,i++,
Print[Prime[i]; ]
```

> ```
> Out: 
> 2
> 3
> 5 
> 7
> ```

And I would like to get these values in a list as well, how do I do that? I was thinking about:

```
Prime/@range@[length[List[Prime[i]<10]]]
```

Comment: `Prime /@ Range@5`

Answer (score 7):

[Jason](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99135/52) has the correct, idiomatic way of approaching this, so I am adding this for completeness as there is a way to capture `Print` output. But, you should not use this unless you have strong reasons to do so. What you can do is to use a handler function to capture the `Print` output. Handlers are executed at specific events, e.g.

```
In[40]:= Internal`Handlers[]

Out[40]= {"VetoableValueChange" -> {JLink`Private`jlinkVetoFunction}, 
 "ValueTrackTrigger" -> {}, "ValueChange" -> {}, "RemoveSymbol" -> {},
  "NewSymbol" -> {}, "GetFileEvent" -> {}, 
 "MessageTextFilter" -> {Internal`MessageButtonHandler}, 
 "Message" -> {}, "Wolfram.System.Print" -> {}, 
 "SystemAssertions" -> {}, "Assertions" -> {}, 
 "ProcessDebugTags" -> {}, "RuntimeToolsActive" -> {}, 
 "BreakPoint" -> {}, "GetSymbol" -> {}, "SetSymbol" -> {}}
```

and most are not active except under specific circumstances (like debug mode). But, [`"Message"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/52), `"MessageTextFilter"`, `"Wolfram.System.Print"` are active all the time.

To set up a handler, there are several functions: `` Internal`HandlerBlock ``, `` Internal`AddHandler ``, and `` Internal`RemoveHandler ``. In this case, it is best to use an `` Internal`HandlerBlock `` as it automatically removes the handler when you are done using it, e.g.

```
Block[{out = {}},
 Internal`HandlerBlock[
  {"Wolfram.System.Print", (out = {out, #}) &},
   For[i = 1, i < 5, i++, Print[Prime[i]];]
  ];
 Flatten@out
]
```

A word of caution, do not use `Print` inside the `"Wolfram.System.Print"` handler as an inescapable infinite loop is entered and you have to forcibly kill the kernel.

Answer (score 6):

All `Print` does is print the numbers in the output line, in this case it is not necessary at all.

There are a few ways of getting the list you are looking for.  The most straightforward, and useful for learning how Mathematica does things, is

```
Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 4, 1}]
(* {2, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

Once you figure out what that means, you can use shorthand to get it quicker

```
Prime@Range@4
(* {2, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

If you want to select only those primes less than a certain number, one direct way to do that is to get a list of primes that is certainly larger than that, and use `Select` to get only the ones you want,

```
Select[Prime@Range@20, (# < 10 &)]
(* {2, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

But the better way, in that it doesn't do more work than is needed, is to follow [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47510/9490)

```
Prime@Range@PrimePi@10
(* {2, 3, 5, 7} *)
```