# How to use Handler functions?

Tags: undocumented, reference-request, message-coding

It seems that `` Internal`AddHandler `` or other functions related to it can be quite helpful sometimes, especially when dealing with messages and such.

But the `Handler` series of functions is undocumented, so I hope maybe someone can give me a brief tutorial of this?

---

## Edit 1

There's an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/6084) which used this feature. There I can get some information about how to use it with Message information, but I think the knowledge I can get there is still quite limited, so maybe someone can give some further explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to contact @Szabolcs to ask him directly?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99170/1871

Comment: Maybe a dev from WRI could post a tutorial? Or maybe there's a Markdown file hidden somewhere in the application folder?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So I have a little bit more info, but mostly a learning technique we can test:

#### Init

I wanted to see when each of these was called so I made each possible handler (without a previous assignment) just call `Print`. Then I found that for `"Wolfram.System.Print"` this is a terrible idea as it is called anytime the system prints. So I removed that. Here's what I'm working off of:

```
With[{h = #},
    Internal`AddHandler[h, Print@(h -> {##}) &]
    ] & /@ 
  DeleteCases[Keys@Internal`Handlers[], 
   "VetoableValueChange" | "Wolfram.System.Print" | "ValueChange" | 
    "Message"
   ];
```

#### Message

`"Message"` works just as described by Szabolcs. Each time a possible message is generated `Hold[mspec_Message, onQ]` gets passed to your handlers.

#### MessageTextFilter

`"MessageTextFilter"` seems to be applied whenever `Message` is called (as best I can tell) which means it doesn't get applied for quieted messages. It takes the sequence `template_String,Hold[mn_MessageName],Hold[mcall_Message]` as its arguments.

If it returns a string, this is passed as the message text. For example:

```
ignoreSet[_, _, Hold[Message[Set::nosym, _]]] :=
  "Well this is fun";

Internal`AddHandler["MessageTextFilter",
 ignoreSet
 ]

_ = 1

Set::nosym: Well this is fun
```

#### NewSymbol

`"NewSymbol"` works pretty much just as `$NewSymbol` does. Everytime a symbol is added to Mathematica's symbol table the handlers get called, being passed `{symName_String,context_String}`.

#### RemoveSymbol

`"RemoveSymbol"` is the exact opposite. Everytime a symbol is removed from that table (I've only gotten this to happen with `Remove`) the same list gets passed to the handlers.

#### ValueChange

`"ValueChange"` can be *very* useful.

I set it like so:

```
Internal`AddHandler["ValueChange", (Print["ValueChange" -> {##}] &)];
```

The symbol in question needs to be tracked internally for it to work, though. I.e. `` Internal`TrackExpression `` or `` Internal`SetValueTrackExtra `` needs to have been called on it so that it's in `` Internal`GetTrackedSymbols[] ``.

It seems to remove the symbol from `` Internal`GetTrackedSymbols[] `` after a single call.

The change cases I've seen look like:

```
Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
Clear[b]

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,Clear]}

Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
Block[{b}, b]

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,Block,True]}

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,Block,False]}

1

Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
Block[{b = 1}, b]

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,Block,True]}

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,Null,1,OwnValues]}

1

Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
b = 1

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,1,1,OwnValues]}

1

Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
b[a_] := c;
Clear[b]

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,b[a_],c,Removed[$$Failure],DownValues]}

Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
z[b[a_]] ^:= c;
Clear[b]

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,z[b[a_]],c,Removed[$$Failure],UpValues]}

Internal`TrackExpression[b, 1];
b[a_][] := c;
Clear[b]

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[b,b[a_][],c,Removed[$$Failure],SubValues]}
```

Note that this will inundate you with change notifications whenever the usage popup menu shows (since there are a pile of FE tracked values there)

One thing to note is that this is part of how `Dynamic` variables are handled:

```
Dynamic[a]

a

a = 1

ValueChange->{HoldComplete[a,1,1,OwnValues]}

1
```

#### ValueTrackTrigger

`"ValueTrackTrigger"` works much like `"ValueChange"`. They get the same arguments and are called under similar circumstances, except `"ValueTrackTrigger"` is called only when values are truly changed and after `"ValueChange"`

#### VetoableValueChange

I've never seen this one in action, but it's worth looking at the handler it comes pre-populated with: `` JLink`Private`jlinkVetoFunction ``. Looking at the `DownValues` on this:

```
HoldPattern[
  JLink`Private`jlinkVetoFunction[
   HoldComplete[JLink`Private`sym_Symbol, JLink`Private`lhs_, 
    JLink`Private`rhs_, _, 
    DownValues]]] :> (JLink`CallJava`Private`setField[
    JLink`Private`lhs, JLink`Private`rhs]; False) /; 
  JavaObjectQ[Unevaluated[JLink`Private`sym]]
```

One sees that the handler should take the argument `HoldComplete[sym_Symbol,lhs_,rhs_,<no_clue_what_this_is>,DownValues]` for setting a down value. And it can clearly reject this proposed change, as the callback does, by returning `False`. For some reason even after adding the handler:

```
Internal`AddHandler["VetoableValueChange",
 Print@("VetoableValueChange" -> {##}) &
 ]
```

I still haven't seen this in action. Might be print protected??

#### GetFileEvent

`"GetFileEvent"` I don't understand completely but I've found a few distinct usages: `HoldComplete[fname_String,Identity,First]` at the start of a `Get` call and `HoldComplete[fname_String,Identity,Last]` at the end (I'm sure there's more meaning in there, I just don't know what it is). And when I did a documentation search with cmd+F I got these two: `` HoldComplete["DocumentationSearch`DocumentationSearch`", Identity, Last] `` and `` HoldComplete[DocumentationSearch`,Identity,Last] ``. Maybe these are special `GetFileEvents` Mathematica records?

#### Misc.

The two I was most eager to see in action are `"GetSymbol"` and `"SetSymbol"` but I have yet to see them called. I'll update this with more stuff when I next know what's up.

#### Cleanup

When I'm done testing I remove all of these handlers with:

```
With[{h = #},
    Internal`RemoveHandler[First@h, #] & /@ Last@h
    ] & /@ Rest@Internal`Handlers[];
```

Comment: SUCH a late but **AWESOME** answer. Hope you can get enough upvotes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

**2023 update**

There is an officially [published function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Experimental/ref/ValueFunction.html), which helps to work with Handlers

```
Experimental`ValueFunction[symbol] = HandlerFunction
```