# Building a function that uses $Assumptions and works like Simplify, FunctionExpand, etc

Tags: function-construction, assumptions, message-coding

I want to write a function `MySimplify` (like built-in `Simplify`) that takes a second argument to specify additional `$Assumptions` and that also has an overriding `Assumptions` option.  Here's how I start:

```
MySimplify::usage = "MySimplify[expr] simplifies expr using QuantumDot's code.
MySimplify[expr, assum] does simplification using assumptions.";

Options[MySimplify] = {Assumptions :> $Assumptions};
SyntaxInformation[MySimplify] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _., OptionsPattern[]}};
```

**Question** How do I write the boiler-plate code to mimic the behavior of built-in `Simplify`?  Here's my attempt:

```
MySimplify[e_, o:OptionsPattern[]] := MySimplify[e, True, o];

MySimplify[e_, a_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Assuming[a,
    Block[{$Assumptions=OptionValue[Assumptions]},
      Null
     (*QuantumDot's code for simplification goes here*)
    ]
  ];
```

The outer `Assuming` appends any assumptions in the second argument to `$Assumptions`, and the inner `Block` uses `$Assumptions`, just like built-in `Simplify`.

**Problem** If I supply assumptions that are contradicting or false, it throws `$Assumptions::cas` instead of `MySimplify::cas`, or `$Assumptions::fas` instead of `MySimplify::fas`.  How do I make the following cases

```
$Assumptions = True;
MySimplify[Sin[x], x > 0 && x < 0];
```

or

```
$Assumptions = a > 0;
MySimplify[Sin[x], x < 0]
```

or

```
MySimplify[Sin[x], Assumptions->False]
```

generate a `MySimplify::cas` and `MySimplify::fas` errors instead of a `$Assumptions::cas` and `$Assumptions::fas` error?

Is this the correct way to build a function that uses assumptions?

Comment: This seems like more of a message filtering issue. If that's the case use `WithMessageHandler` to catch messages and reemit them with the appropriate head or use a different handler built at the ``Internal`HandlerBlock`` level.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Those are two very interesting functions, where can I read to learn more about them?

Comment: I think they're only really documented here... Check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120159/how-to-use-handler-functions/139718#139718) and `WithMessageHandler`... you can look [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/GeneralUtilities/ref/WithMessageHandler.html) I guess, although that's a bit ugly and autobuilt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already mimicking the behavior of MMA built-in functions. The following code prints a `$Assumptions::cas` message not a `TensorDimensions::cas`.

```
$Assumptions = A \[Element] Arrays[{2, 2, 2, 2}];
Assuming[A \[Element] Arrays[{2, 2}], Print["QD was here…"];TensorDimensions[A]]
(*error message before QD gets there*)
```

Note that the error is printed before the message. That suggests that `Assuming` processes the assumptions before moving on to the evaluation of the code in the second parameter. Checking the attributes further supports that suggestion:

```
Attributes[Assuming]
{HoldRest, Protected}
```

If one must have one's own message, one could try evaluating `$Assumptions` within a `Quiet` block.

```
Options[qdSimplify] = {Assumptions :> $Assumptions};

qdSimplify[e_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := qdSimplify[e, True, o];

qdSimplify[e_, a_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{qdAssumptions = 
     Quiet[Check[
       Assuming[a && OptionValue[Assumptions], $Assumptions], 
       Print["Your ad here"]; True], {$Assumptions::cas}]}, 
   Print["Bleached assumptions: ", qdAssumptions]; 
   Assuming[qdAssumptions, Print[qdAssumptions]; 
    Print[$Assumptions];]];

$Assumptions = True;
qdSimplify[Sin[x], x > 0 && x < 0];
```

Of course, one would have to determine what to do in case of contradiction (perhaps devising some preference semantics) … but that is the subject for another question.

---

**Update**

I am not sure that I understand your request.

If it about suppressing the message `$Assumptions::fas`, you could just add it to the list that contains `$Assumptions::cas`.

If it is about printing your own message, you can replace `Print["Your ad here"]` with your own `Message[blah]`.

If you want to reproduce the fact that `Simplify` with contradictory assumptions evaluates to True, you can do it by changing the `True` after `Print` with a flag that you check in the body.

Maybe you want all of the above.

```
Options[qdSimplify] = {Assumptions :> $Assumptions};

(*As pointed out by b3m2a1, the next two lines are not necessary*)
(*
qdSimplify::fas="Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False";
qdSimplify::cas="Warning: contradictory assumption(s) encountered: `1`."*)
qdSimplifyContr::usage = "This is a flag indicating contradictory assumptions.";
qdSimplifyFalse::usage = "This is a flag indicating false assumptions.";

qdSimplify[e_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := qdSimplify[e, True, o];

qdSimplify[e_, a_, OptionsPattern[]] := With[{qdAssumptions = Quiet[
      Check[
       Check[
        Assuming[a && OptionValue[Assumptions], $Assumptions], 
        Message[qdSimplify::cas, a && OptionValue[Assumptions]]; qdSimplifyContr,
        {$Assumptions::cas}],
       Message[qdSimplify::fas]; qdSimplifyFalse,
       {$Assumptions::fas}],
      {$Assumptions::cas, $Assumptions::fas}]}, 
   Print["Bleached assumptions: ", qdAssumptions];
   Which[
    (*A*)! FreeQ[qdAssumptions, qdSimplifyContr], True,
    (*B*)! FreeQ[qdAssumptions, qdSimplifyFalse], "Handled false assumptions",
    (*C*)True, 
    Assuming[qdAssumptions, Print[qdAssumptions]; Print[$Assumptions];
      "Normal code"]]];
```

A. Simulates the fact that Simplify with contradictory assumptions evaluates to True.
B. This is where you would handle the situation with false assumptions.
C. This is where you would put the body of the function.

Comment: Thanks, but, how about mimicking all other aspects, like for `$Assumptions::fas` (see edit)?

Comment: `::fas` and `::cas` are already attached to `General`. You don't need to redefine them.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Are you suggesting that, instead of `qdSimplify::fas = "blah"`, the code should have `qdSimplify::fas = General::fas`? If so, I concur with you.

Comment: @Hector no I'm saying never assign to `qdSimplify::fas`. Literally just try a raw ``Message[bleb::fas]`` without attaching a message to `bleb`. That's the real point of `General`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Huh ... I just learned something new!

Comment: Thanks for the modification... +1 for your answer.  I'm going to put this question on a bounty to see if there is a cleaner way to do all the checks so it works just like *Mathematica* built in functions.