# How to decorate cells with widgets like jupyter and collab?

Tags: front-end, cells, stylesheet

I would like to add a couple UI features from cells in python notebooks that I find helpful. Specifically, these two features from google's collaboratory and vs-code's jupyter mode:

To the left of each code/input cell,

1. Add timing information
2. Add icon showing whether the cell was successfully run or had errors/warnings
3. Add length of output in tooltip (if applicable)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Here's a first attempt:

```
byteString[b_] :=
 Which[
  b < 10^3, ToString[b] <> "B",
  b < 10^6, ToString[NumberForm[b/10.^3, 3]] <> "kB",
  b < 10^9, ToString[NumberForm[b/10.^6, 3]] <> "MB",
  True, ToString[NumberForm[b/10.^9, 3]] <> "GB"
  ]

handler = Replace[Hold[_, True] :> (errors = True)];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 {
  CellProlog :> (
    startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
    outSize = 0;
    aborted = False;
    $PrePrint = (
       outSize += ByteCount[#];
       If[MatchQ[#, $Aborted|$Aborted[]], aborted = True;];
       #
       ) &;
    errors = False;
    SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],
     CellDingbat -> ToBoxes@Pane[
        ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace", ImageSize -> 12], 
        FrameMargins -> 3
        ]
     ];
    Internal`AddHandler["Message", handler];
    ),
  CellEpilog :> (
    SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],
     CellDingbat -> ToBoxes@
       If[outSize > 0,
         Tooltip[#,
           Style[Row@{byteString[outSize]}, 8.5, GrayLevel@0.3]
           ] &,
         # &]@Style[
         Column[
          {
           Which[
            errors, Style["\[WarningSign]", 20, Red],
            aborted, Style["\[WarningSign]", 20, Orange],
            True, Style["✓", 20, Darker@Green]
            ],
           Style[
            GeneralUtilities`TimeString[AbsoluteTime[] - startTime],
            8.5, GrayLevel@0.7
            ]
           },
          Center, -0.3
          ],
         ShowStringCharacters -> False
         ]
     ];
    $PrePrint =.;
    Quiet@Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", handler];
    )
  }
 ]

Pause@1

1/0
(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. *)
(* ComplexInfinity *)

Table[i^2, {i, 100}]
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, \
225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, \
841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, \
1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, \
2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, \
3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, \
5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, \
7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, \
9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000} *)
```

[image]

This makes use of [`CellProlog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellProlog.html), [`CellEpilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEpilog.html) and [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html), together with [message handlers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120159/how-to-use-handler-functions). Some notes:

- As can be seen by the screenshot above, there are currently four different states that can be displayed: Currently running (indicated by the spinner), completed with messages (red warning sign), completed without messages (green checkmark) and aborted (orange warning sign). For completed/aborted cells, the total time is displayed, and the tooltip contains the total number of bytes of the output (if there is any)
- I first tried to use `CellEvaluationFunction` to wrap the actual evaluation. Unfortunately, we get the box structure of the entire cell like that, which makes processing rather difficult. `CellProlog` and `CellEpilog` on the other hand do not interfere with the actual evaluation at all, and have thus a significantly lower risk of breaking anything.
- I am using a message handler to detect if any message was actually printed during the evaluation of the cell. See [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120159/how-to-use-handler-functions) for an explanation of how they work.
- The timing is done by recording the [`AbsoluteTime`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime.html) before and after the evaluation.
- The results are displayed in a [`CellDingbat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDingbat.html)
- I am measuring the output size by looking setting `$PrePrint` and measuring the [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) of everything that will be printed.
- I check for aborted evaluations by comparing the expressions passes to `$PrePrint` to `$Aborted` and `$Aborted[]`. This might fail in some weird edge cases, but should mostly work.
- This approach uses `$PrePrint`, `CellProlog` and `CellEpilog`. So if any of those are set by some other code, this will break.
- The current version just sets the `CellProlog` and `CellEpilog` options at the notebook level, but it should be easy enough to put this into a stylesheet.

Comment: `ResourceFunction["DarkMode"][]`

Comment: Can you make it work in that style? I think just making the dingbat background transparent would do it.

Comment: I'm in 13.1, this is [my effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXE3F.png)

Comment: @yode I can reproduce the same behavior... It seems they changed how cell labels interact with cell dingbats in 13.1 (The underlying styles are the same, so it must be something more fundamental). Unfortunately, I don't know how to change the behavior

Comment: @yode It looks like you might be able to get something nicer looking using `CellDingbatMargins` and `CellLabelMargins`, e.g. `SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],  CellDingbat -> ToBoxes@Column[{Style["", 30], Style["\[MathematicaIcon]", ShowStringCharacters -> False]}, Center], CellDingbatMargin -> 20, CellLabelMargins -> {{20, 0}, {-14, 0}}]`

Comment: @user5601 I couldn't find a nice way to get it to look perfectly. As far as I can tell, it's impossible to disable the inheritance of the background color. You can try to set the background color of the `CellDingbat` to `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Notebook", Background}]`, but that leaves some ugly borders at the top and bottom for me