# Finding the largest integer that cannot be partitioned in a certain way

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, partitions

I want to use *Mathematica* to solve the problem:

> Find the maximum $k$ such that $6x+9y+20z=k$ does not have a non-negative solution.

I tried `FrobeniusSolve`. But what is the elegant way to find the maximum?

I know the theoretical background of this problem, and I know other ways of getting the solution. But I want to see how this can be done elegantly in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. If positive x, y, z are a solution for a given k, then n*x, n*y and n*z are a solution for n*k.  So it seems to me there is no maximum k.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it is expected that there are infinitely many k that have a solution. In fact the question seem to assume that for some N, all k>N have solutions. We wish to find the smallest such N. That is the same as to say, we wish to find the largest k that does not have a solution. I think.

Comment: The short answer to this question is to use `FrobeniusNumber[{6, 9, 20}]`.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinProblem.html if you want to implement something yourself. There is a downloadable notebook.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I guess we're reading different things in the question and I'm afraid I don't see any grounds for your interpretation based on the literal text of the question. The question asks for a maximum k and I feel it's pretty clear there can generally not be a maximum k.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I feel the question has been stated almost the same in both the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrobeniusNumber.html) and on [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I guess the double negatives were getting at me. BTW Do you understand why `FrobeniusSolve[{12, 16, 20, 27}, 88]` and `FrobeniusSolve[{12, 16, 20, 27}, 90]` both find non-negative solutions whereas the Frobenius number of this series is supposed to be `FrobeniusNumber[{12, 16, 20, 27}]==89`?

Comment: Can be set up as follows. `Resolve[Exists[n, 
  n >= 1 && 
   ForAll[k, 
    Implies[k > n, 
     Exists[{x, y, z}, 
      x >= 0 && y >= 0 && 
       z >= 0 && {6, 9, 20}.{x, y, z} == k]]]], Integers]`. I would not be surprised if it takes around infinitely long to resolve this though.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom You are right, consider switching your comment to an answer.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The double negatives also get to me :). I had to really think about your last comment. Maybe evaluate `Table[
  {iiii, FrobeniusSolve[{12, 16, 20, 27}, iiii, 1]}, {iiii, 
   500}] // Column`. The point is that for iiii>89, there is always a solution. We may also not have a solution for iiii=85, but 89 is the largest number for which we have no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `FrobeniusNumber` instead of `FrobeniusSolve`, since it serves this purpose

> The Frobenius number of $a_{1}, ... a_{n}$,.is the largest integer b for which the Frobenius equation  $a_{1} x_{1}+ ... a_{n} x_{n} = k$ has no non-negative integer solutions. The $a_{i}$ must be positive integers.

```
FrobeniusNumber[{6, 9, 20}]
```

> ```
> 43
> ```

Nevertheless you can still get the result playing with `FrobeniusSolve`, there might be many possible ways, let's point out one of them using `Cases` with an appropriate replacement rule e.g.

```
Max @ Cases[ Table[{ k, FrobeniusSolve[{6, 9, 20}, k] != {}}, {k, 100}], {a_, False} -> a]
```

> ```
> 43
> ```

In case of not knowing `FrobeniusNumber`, one can get an idea also with `Reduce` or `Solve` although these ways are not recommended for diophantine equations, see e.g. [Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation).

Comment: That looks good, I am glad you did it, I will go to sleep :).

Comment: I'd use `FindInstance` in preference to `Reduce`, for the particular task of deciding existence (of solutions).

Comment: @Artes Yeah, no surprise the quantifier elimination would need either infinite time or memory, and possibly both.