# Find the smallest positive integer that satisfies a certain condition

Tags: functional-style, implementation-details, searching

I know Mathematica is really powerful when it comes to functional operations like applying a list of tasks to a list of variables. Sometimes I feel like it isn't the most powerful tool when it comes to looking for a number in a large range. But that's what I'd like to use it for regardless. I can always use a `While` loop, but I'm not sure that is the most effective way of doing it. So I'm looking for a more elegant/effective way of doing this. Let me give you an example:

Question: Find the smallest positive integer whose sum of its digits squared is greater than 100.

My rather sloppy solution:

```
myInt = 0;
mySum = 0;
SumLimit = 100;
While[mySum < SumLimit,
 myDigits = IntegerDigits[myInt];
 mySum = Total[#^2 & /@ myDigits];
 myInt = myInt + 1;
]
myInt - 1
```

And the answer is 59.

But as you can clearly see, this method is quite slow. If I said 1000 instead of 100, it would take quite a long time to find. There are obviously better ways to solve this problem than brute force, but I'd basically like to have a more elegant implementation of the brute force method.

Comment: No, you can't use Range[100]. What would you use if I said 10^5 instead of 10^2?

Comment: just tightening it up helps a little: ` `While[Total@(IntegerDigits[++myInt]^2) < SumLimit]`

Comment: @george2079 I like to have individual statements for the readability of the code.

Comment: @Öskå I think it's safe to say most people are bad with `Compile` and that just shows that it's implementation and documentation are terrible @Kuba.

Comment: Look at a related problem: [Finding the largest integer that cannot be partitioned in a certain way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26026/finding-the-largest-integer-that-cannot-be-partitioned-in-a-certain-way/26033#26033)

Answer (score 9):

I *think* this works correctly:

```
ClearAll[min, doMin];
min[x_] := 
  doMin[x] // Reap // Last // Flatten // Reverse // FromDigits;
doMin[x_] :=
  With[
   {d = Range[9]^2},
   If[
    x > 81,
    Sow@ConstantArray[9, IntegerPart[x/81]]; doMin[Mod[x, 81]],
    Sow@Sqrt@Select[d, # >= x &, 1]]];

min[100] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.001005, 59}

```
min[1000000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.024029, .... }

Comment: @mfvonh - I agree with the "59", but I don't agree with the "..."

Comment: @eldo Can you show me an instance where it produces the wrong answer? `min[1000000] // IntegerDigits // #^2 & // Total` == 1000009

Comment: @mfvonh I think it was a joke..

Comment: @mfvonh - I'm sorry, but I don't see the answer on my screen for  `min[1000000] // AbsoluteTiming`. I just see the timing and after that "...".  An appeal court could reject the answer because of this :)

Comment: @eldo Oh I see, you just mean in the post? If so, I left the answer out because it is 12,346 digits long :P

Comment: Maybe that's not a clear way to do that?

Comment: @mfvonh - well, the poor judges have to go through this, and they don't know it any better. Clear win for you.

Comment: @eldo I will take pride in my (tentative) victory since I am usually several orders of magnitude behind the pack :)

Answer (score 5):

I thinks this is short, easy, and fast solution:

```
x = 100;
n = FromDigits@
  Flatten@{Ceiling@Sqrt[x - 9^2 Floor@(x/9^2)], 
    ConstantArray[9, (Floor@(x/9^2))]}

59
```

Please try it and let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, what do you think?

Comment: I consider your solution to be the best so far presented. It's even faster than mfvonh's method. I got 0.034 seconds for `x = 10^7`. Plus it seems to hold for all values >= 0. You can get an extra speed gain by defining `w = Floor@(x/9^2)` at the beginning :)

Comment: @eldo, thanks for your comments.

Comment: My tentative victory vanishes :)

Comment: @mfvonh, I am always amazed by your knowledge of Mathematica. I wish I could be someday expert in Mathematica like you or like Mr. Wizard. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thank you, I am flattered! (Though I would say MrWizard is a few leagues above me.) I'm sure you will be impressed with how much you know sooner rather than later. I've just been learning Mathematica casually for about a year and a half, and this site has helped enormously. At some point the Mathematica "mentality" starts to click -- it just takes time and practice.

Comment: @mfvonh Thanks for the advice. I will keep practice and practice and hopefully Mathematica starts to click.

Comment: It seems to me like it's already starting to :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    Minimize[{d0 + 10 d1 + 10^2 d2, d0^2 + d1^2 + d2^2 > 100, 
  d0 == 0 || d0 == 1 || d0 == 2 || d0 == 3 || d0 == 4 || d0 == 5 || 
   d0 == 6 || d0 == 7 || d0 == 8 || d0 == 9, 
  d1 == 0 || d1 == 1 || d1 == 2 || d1 == 3 || d1 == 4 || d1 == 5 || 
   d1 == 6 || d1 == 7 || d1 == 8 || d1 == 9, 
  d2 == 0 || d2 == 1 || d2 == 2 || d2 == 3 || d2 == 4 || d2 == 5 || 
   d2 == 6 || d2 == 7 || d2 == 8 || d2 == 9}, {d0, d1, d2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll propose two modifications to this problem [Read: I want to change it to make my proposed method look better]. First we up the constraint bound so that exhaustive search is more, well, exhausting. Then we weight the summands so that the method used by @Brian Megquier becomes more difficult to employ.

Specifically I raised the threshold from 100 to 10000 and I multiply the square of the jth digit by the jth prime. Again the objective is to find the smallest number subject to this threshold constraint. The method I used is 0-1 integer linear programming, mostly because it's all I know.

Here I set this up for a call to `NMinimize`. It recognizes ILPs and forks them over to some COIN-CLP library code.

```
squaresSumMin = 10000;
nvars = 15;
digits = Array[d, {nvars, 10}];
fvars = Flatten[digits];
c1 = Map[Total[#] == 1 &, digits];
c2 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, fvars];
c3 = {Prime[Range[nvars]].(digits.(Range[0, 9]^2)) >= squaresSumMin, 
   Element[fvars, Integers]};
obj = 10^Range[0, nvars - 1].(digits.Range[0, 9]);
constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3];

Timing[{min, vals} = NMinimize[{obj, constraints}, Flatten[digits]];]

(* Out[301]= {0.044000, Null} *)
```

Here is the winner.

```
Round[min]

(* Out[303]= 9899999989 *)
```

I actually checked this with a much slower run through (exact) `Minimize`, and it agrees after 20 minutes or so of deep soul searching.

A caveat is that this method will also have trouble should we go much higher with the threshold. I believe it is because the library code eventually has difficulty with machine precision arithmetic giving integers to close enough approximation. One could code an explicit branch-and-prune loop though I've not done so for this example.

Answer (score 2):

Figure out how many nines,then fill the 1st number with the smallest non nine that works. This example is just to show the algorithm using pseudo code.

```
myInt=0
mySum=1000  \\or whatever
numNines=mySum/81

numNines=numNines-(numNines mod 1)  \\convert to int without rounding

for i=8 to 1; i--
  if (mySum mod 81) > i^2
    myInt=i

if numNines>=1
  for  j=0 to (numNines-1); j++
    myInt= (myInt*10) + 9
```

Comment: sure if you want to think about the problem instead of diving in and writing code  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is among all the tuples with the same digits only the one sorted lowest needs to be checked. That sort/union operation is much faster than the total^2 operation so it is worthwhile:

```
 SumLimit = 450
 First@(FromDigits /@ 
       Select[Union@(Sort /@ Tuples[Range[0, 9], {Ceiling[SumLimit/81]}]),
           Total@(#^2) > SumLimit &])
```

> {0.608404, 799999}

Faster still, here we avoid generating all the tuples to begin with.

```
 nd = Ceiling[SumLimit/81]+1;
 First@Sort[
     FromDigits /@ 
        Select[ #[[2]] & /@ 
           Nest[( Flatten[
              Map[(next = #[[1]] + 1;
                {next, #} & /@ ({#[[2]]}~Join~ Table[ Join[#[[2]] ,
                 ConstantArray[#[[1]], i ] ], {i, 1, 
                      nd - Length[#[[2]]]}])) & , #, 1], 1]) &  , {{0, {}}} , 10]  , 
                        Length[#] == nd && Total[#^2] > SumLimit&]] // Timing
```

> {0.140401, 799999}

Answer (score 1):

I could have written this as an oneliner, but I show it step for step:

```
x1 = Tuples[Range@9, 2];
x2 = First[#]^2 + Last[#]^2 & /@ x1;
p = First@Position[x2, x_ /; x > 100];
x1[[p]]
```

> {{5, 9}}

Lots of possible improvements here, but it's late and I go.

Answer (score 1):

If we do choose brute force this question is a duplicate of:  [Iterate until condition is met](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584/121).

I would suggest starting with `Select` as I explained in my answer there.  Also, try to vectorize operations (such as `Power`) as often as possible.  Compare:

```
Select[Range@1*^6, Tr[IntegerDigits[#]^2] > 450 &, 1] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.544, {799999}}
> ```

```
myInt = 0;
mySum = 0;
SumLimit = 450;
While[mySum < SumLimit, myDigits = IntegerDigits[myInt];
  mySum = Total[#^2 & /@ myDigits];
  myInt = myInt + 1;] // Timing
myInt - 1
```

> ```
> {5.975, Null}
>
> 799999
> ```

The range (`Range@1*^6`) was arbitrarily chosen; to make this open-ended I would use the block-based method I also described in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? You may use the "select" built-in function

[image: Mathematica Selecting]

Comment: How is this different from the answer posted above by @Mr.Wizard? You just changed `Tr` to `Total`