# How can I select elements that are true?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of lists. For example,

```
 list = {{0,1,0,1,true},{0,0,0,0,false},{0,1,1,1,true},{1,1,1,1,false},{2,2,2,2,false}}
```

I'd like to find all lists that have the fifth element set to `true`.  I'm looking for a general method that works for any lists in this format. How can I do this?

In the above example, the result that I'm looking for would be:

```
 {{0,1,0,1,true},{0,1,1,1,true}}
```

Sorry for such a basic question.  I looked through the documentation for lists and couldn't find a way to do this.  I'm still fairly new at *Mathematica*.

Comment: Have you tried Cases or Select?  `true` is a proper symbol, but be aware that Mathematica represents truth values with `True` and `False` (not `true`)

Comment: `Cases[{{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 0, 0, 0, false}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 
   true}, {1, 1, 1, 1, false}, {2, 2, 2, 2, false}}, {___, true, ___}]`, see also `DeleteCases` e.g. in this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation/10569#10569)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several options and this is probably a duplicate although I can't seem to find it. A few of them to try out and learn:

```
list = {{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 0, 0, 0, false}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, false}, {2, 2, 2, 2, false}};

Cases[list, {__, true}]
Select[list, Last@# === true &]
DeleteCases[list, {__, false}]
Pick[list, list, {__, true}] /. {} -> Sequence[]
```

all of which return

```
(* {{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}} *)
```

If your data has `True` and `False` instead of `true` and `false`, then you can simplify the `Select` example to:

```
Select[list, Last]
```

Comment: `Scan[
  If[#[[-1]] === true, Sow[#]] &,
  list] // Reap`

Comment: `Extract[list, Position[list, true][[;; , {1}]]]`

Comment: `Pick[list, list[[All, 5]], true]`

Answer (score 3):

as @Szabolcs pointed out, MMA is case sensitive and true is treated as a symbol and not as a variable, thus.

```
data = {{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 0, 0, 0, false}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 
true}, {1, 1, 1, 1, false}, {2, 2, 2, 2, false}};
Select[data, MatchQ[#[[5]], true] &]
(*{{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}}*)
```

If the data is entered accordingly (with True and False) then

```
data = {{0, 1, 0, 1, True}, {0, 0, 0, 0, False}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 
   True}, {1, 1, 1, 1, False}, {2, 2, 2, 2, False}};    
Select[data, TrueQ[#[[5]]] &]
(*{{0, 1, 0, 1, True}, {0, 1, 1, 1, True}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 0, 0, 0, false}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, false}, {2, 2, 2, 2, false}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {__, Except[false]}, ___} :> s]

(*{{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}}*)
```

Or using `Replace`:

```
Replace[list, s : {__, false} :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 0, 0, 0, false}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}, 
  {1, 1, 1, 1, false}, {2, 2, 2, 2, false}}
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{__, false}}]
```

{{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[Position[list, {__, false}]] @ list
```

{{0, 1, 0, 1, true}, {0, 1, 1, 1, true}}