# How can I reduce my code and can I remove word `True` from the result?

Tags: list-manipulation

At here [How can I select elements that are true](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/how-can-i-select-elements-that-are-true)

```
list={{{2, 4, -3}, {3, 5, -1}}, {{2, 4, -3}, {3, 5, 7}}, {{2, 4, -3}, {5, 
   1, 9}}, {{2, 4, 9}, {3, 5, -1}}, {{2, 4, 9}, {3, 5, 7}}, {{2, 4, 
   9}, {5, 1, -3}}, {{3, 2, -4}, {5, 1, -3}}, {{3, 2, -4}, {5, 1, 
   9}}, {{3, 2, -4}, {5, 4, 6}}, {{3, 2, 10}, {5, 1, -3}}, {{3, 2, 
   10}, {5, 1, 9}}, {{3, 2, 10}, {5, 4, 6}}, {{3, 5, -1}, {6, 2, 
   7}}, {{3, 5, -1}, {7, 2, 4}}, {{3, 5, 7}, {6, 2, -1}}, {{3, 6, 
   2}, {5, 1, -3}}, {{3, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 9}}, {{3, 6, 4}, {5, 
   1, -3}}, {{3, 6, 4}, {5, 1, 9}}, {{5, 1, -3}, {6, 2, -1}}, {{5, 
   1, -3}, {6, 2, 7}}, {{5, 1, -3}, {7, 2, 4}}, {{5, 1, 9}, {6, 
   2, -1}}, {{5, 1, 9}, {6, 2, 7}}, {{5, 1, 9}, {7, 2, 4}}}
```

I want to Select from list an element {pA,pB}so that `Mod[pA + pB, 2] == {0, 0, 0}`. I tried

```
Table[{pA, pB} = points;
  {pA, pB, Mod[pA + pB, 2] == {0, 0, 0}}, {points, list}];
Cases[list2, {__, True}]
```

I got

> {{{3, 2, -4}, {5, 4, 6}, True}, {{3, 2, 10}, {5, 4, 6}, True}}

Can I reduce my code and can I remove word `True` to get,

> {{{3, 2, -4}, {5, 4, 6}}, {{3, 2, 10}, {5, 4, 6}}}

Comment: As you yourself say, use `Select`: `Select[list, Mod[#[[1]] + #[[2]], 2] == {0, 0, 0} &]`

Comment: A variation of @swish's solution uses the selection function `Mod[Total[#], 2] == {0, 0, 0} &`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Pick` is typically faster than `Select`. On large lists, I would recommend

```
Pick[list, Total[Mod[Total[list, {2}], 2], {2}], 0]
```

which is 10 or 20 times faster than these variations.

```
Select[list, Mod[Total[#], 2] == {0, 0, 0} &]

Cases[list, _?(Total[Mod[Total[#], 2]] == 0 &)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html):

```
{{{3, 2, -4}, {5, 4, 6}, True}, {{3, 2, 10}, {5, 4, 6}, True}} /. True -> Nothing

(* {{{3, 2, -4}, {5, 4, 6}}, {{3, 2, 10}, {5, 4, 6}}} *)
```