# removing list containing zeros

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists which looks something like this-
`{{12,1,23,.....,4},{0,0,0,.....,0},{34,67,5,.....,60},{0,0,0,.....,0}}`. I want list to look something like - `{{12,1,23,....,4},{34,67,5,.....,60}}`. I want to remove all those lists which have zero as their only element. How can It be done?

Comment: Something related can be found in this post: [Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation/10569#10569)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list = {{12, 1, 23, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {34, 67, 5, 60}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};

DeleteCases[ list , {0 ..}]
(* {{12, 1, 23, 4}, {34, 67, 5, 60}} *)

(* this also results in the same answer *)
Cases[ list , Except@{0 ..}]

(* or *)
list /. {0 ..} :> Sequence[]

(* using select *)
Select[ list , x \[Function] FreeQ[x, {0 ..}] ]

(* assuming no negative integers *)
Select[ list , Total @ # != 0 &]
```

Comment: caution: the last method with `Select` assumes that there are no negative integers !

Comment: I thought my edit helps readability. Please, roll back, if you think it does not. (+1) for a nice answer!

Comment: @gwr thanks for the edit. it is definitely better now

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility as of Version 11:

```
lists = {{12, 1, 23, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {34, 67, 5, 60}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};

lists /. {0..} -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight addition:

```
Pick[dat, Total /@ Unitize@dat, Except[0 | _List]]
```

Just providing some other methods of solving similar problems.